# Infinitely many primes of the form $16n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

As the title states I need to prove there are infinitely primes of the form $16n+1$ but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. In your case, have you researched any similar propositions, such as for the form $4n+1$? What relevant theorems have you already learned?